# Is there a latin root for Romanian thank you (“mulțumesc”)?

Tags: idiom

The Romanian language has a particular word to express “thank you”. This word appears composite and direct translation of Latin. Phonetically I find it identical if not peculiarly close to “mult sum es[t] cum”, however I couldn’t find much meaning in an expression as such, despite my attempts to find it in common phrases and proverbs of Latin.

The reason I believe in this construct is simple: every vowel and consonant comes in the right place to produce the sound of the word.

Is there anyone aware of a vulgar Latin construct of the kind “mult sum es[t] cum”?

Comment: I know almost nothing of Latin and less about phonetics or Romanian but as a shop-worker who happens to have met Romanian customers every six weeks or so for years, I notice that they pronounce 'mulțumesc' like 'multo mutz' which sounds like Italian 'many' followed by Spanish 'much'.

I don't suggest those sounds are exclusive to Spanish or Italian and I do notice, eg, nytimes.com (no spamming here) 1995/06/17/opinion/l-romania-s-name-reflects-true-roman-origins-955295.html tells us 'Romanians are descendants of the Romans and Dacians and do speak a romance language similar to Italian'

Comment: why `mult sum` and not `multum est`?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Maybe you refer to a popular or regional form of "thank you" [`mulțam`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mulțam) instead of `mulțumesc` (see my comments under answer),  where `u` is pronounced like `o` in `do` an `a` like `u` in `cut`, otherwise I cannot imagine what that is you heard.

Comment: @cipricus Maybe I do, and I suggest nothing beyond what I actually Posted.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no such Latin phrase. In fact, *mult* isn't even a Latin word.

I don't know enough about Romanian to offer a definitive etymology, but Wiktionary says it comes from [la mulți ani](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_mul%C8%9Bi_ani#Romanian), "for many years."

This yields a verb, [*mulțumi*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mul%C8%9Bumi#Romanian), and *mulțumesc* is the first person singular present indicative, third person plural present indicative, or first person singular subjunctive.

However, *mulți ani* does ultimately come from Latin. An equivalent phrase might be *multis annis* or *ad multos annos*. In the former, we do get a phrase like *valeas, multis annis imperes* as a sort of valediction, a wish that Alexander Severus rule for a long time. Languages do weird things for "thanks", including English ("cheers") and Portuguese ("valeu"). I can see this being a toast of sorts in gratitude for some favor or service, which after a while becomes a standard way for thanking someone.

That last bit is idle speculation, though, and perhaps someone might add more to the story.

---

Thanks to brianpck who notes that [*ad multos annos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_multos_annos) was at some point a standard way of congratulating people. That actually makes it a strong candidate for the origin of *la mulți ani*.

Comment: Perhaps an even closer equivalent is [*ad multos annos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_multos_annos).

Comment: @brianpck Ha, that's what I had at first (though with a typo). I'll add that back in and credit you for finding that.

Comment: Is there any chance that the expression "multum est" (meaning "that is very satisfactory") could have been used for thanking? - like in the proverb "Si satis est, multum est". Note that ”mulțumi” (to say thanks) also means transitively ”to satisfy”, "mulțumit”, past participle of *mulțumi* never means "(one that was) thanked", but just "satisfied",  "mulțumitor”, apparently meaning ”the one that thanks” in fact means "satisfactory", while "mulțumire” rather rarely and only in plural (”mulțumiri”) means ”thank-you(-s)”, in most cases meaning ”satisfaction”.

Comment: I feel that the basic meaning of the verb *mulțumi* is ”to satisfy” and only secondarily ”to thank”.

Comment: @cipricus I think that's distinct enough that it warrants a question of its own.

Comment: My impression may be misleading though, as the idea of "mulți ani" having precedence seems supported by the older/regional forms "mulțămi” (instead of ”mulțumi”) and ”mulțam” (instead of ”mulțumesc”). Also, `-um` in `multum` being transmitted to Romanian would be a notable exception I guess. - On the other hand the n>m translation isn't expected either I guess. (Not sure of either in fact.)